# Get Repeater data with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a Repeater in my page and after databinding, I have to click on a button to postback in page, and I need to do a `foreach` in all data from my Repeater.
In true I have to get each item inside `foreach` statment as example.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in rptSpecialEquipments.Items)
{
   // Get Data From My Repeater
}
```

Best Regards,

Milton Câmara Gomes

Comment: Are you sure you need to step through the entire list? Are you looking, perhaps, for the selected item?

Comment: No, I realy need to step through the entire list, cause I have an DropDownList for each item. And I have to know whats the DropDownList Item is selected, and if so, I have to take the actual DataItem that Dropdown list is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in rptSpecialEquipments.Items)
    {
        //to get the dropdown of each line
        DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("the name of your dropdown control here");

        //to get the selected value of your dropdownlist
        string value = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to get too the actual data object from RepeaterItem.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What do you mean by "data object"?

Comment: sounds like you need `DataItem data = (DataItem)yourDropDown.SelectedItem;` ?

Answer (score 1):

when you are declaring RepeaterItem as itemEquipment then  (dropDownList) should be be found in itemEquipment not item

so correct code would be  as below. 
I tried to edit the answer above but the person who reviewed it rejected by edition.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in rptSpecialEquipments.Items)
    {
        //to get the dropdown of each line
        DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl("the name of your dropdown control here");

        //to get the selected value of your dropdownlist
        string value = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
```