# Asp C# get control in repeat

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have this html/marckup code

```
<div class="col-md-12  pre-scrollable"> 
    <asp:repeater runat="server" ID="rptDataInputs">
        <itemtemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput"><asp:Literal ID="Literal22" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' runat="server" /></label>  
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <asp:textbox ID="tb_value" MaxLength="10" runat="server" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:10px;" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <asp:CheckBox Text="" runat="server" Checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Insert").Equals("1") %>'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label runat="server" id="lbl_break"><input runat="server" id="break" type="radio" name="optradio"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                                                                    
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
</div>
```

i need to get the value in the radio for each line.

How could i do this?

Comment: You can get control value using foreach take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915758/get-repeater-data-with-foreach

Comment: Where do you need it? In front or backend. And when? Page load, PostBack, DataBind? There is not enough info.